# Multiple readings for singular 魚

Tags: kanji, readings

In what situations is `魚` pronounced as 「うお」 vs. 「さかな」?  I personally like 「うお」 better, but I don't know why.  Is it reserved for only certain scenarios?

Comment: 「ぎょ」もありますが、どうでしょう。^^　edit: あ、単独で使うときの話？「うお」って、古い感じで（文語的？詩的？）、日常では使わないですね。

Comment: You can like what you like but I could personally promise that you would sound more than weird to the vast majority of Japanese-speakers if you used うお by itself to refer to a fish in ANY real-life situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This webpage has a comprehensive explanation: http://www.kyoiku-shuppan.co.jp/view.rbz?nd=1644&ik=1&pnp=100&pnp=106&pnp=134&pnp=1644&cd=89

> 「うお」は記紀万葉の時代から魚類の総称として使われているが，「さかな」が同様の意味で使われ始めたのは比較的新しく，近世になってからのようである。もともとは「さか（酒）＋な（副食物の総称）」で酒を飲むときに添えて食べる物，いわゆる「酒のさかな（肴）」を意味した。（「な」は「魚」のことで，「酒魚」の意，あるいは，「なぐさむ（慰）」の「な」である，などの語源説もある。）それが転じて，魚類の総称の意に使われ，近世になると，例えば「魚市」の場合，「うおいち」「さかないち」の両様の言い方が行われるようになった。
>
> では，現代ではどうなっているかだが，まず，「魚河岸・魚市場・魚心・白魚・魚屋・小魚・魚売り」などの「魚」については，問題ないだろう。また，魚屋に並んでいる「魚」，副食物としての「魚」の類を，「さかな」と言うのも異論がないと思われる。問題なのは，水中にある「魚」であり，その周辺の「魚釣り・川魚」などである。大ざっぱにいって，古語が比較的多く残っている西日本では，「うお」（ないしは「いお」）が使われ，関東では，「さかな」が用いられているようである。
>   したがって，「魚」に「うお」と「さかな」の二つの訓が認められている現在，水中にある「魚」をどちらかに限定することは不可能で，むしろ地域地域の実態にまかせるしかないと思われる。
>   しかし，教育現場において，どちらかに限定する必要にせまられ，それを判断する根拠が見いだせない場合は，現在では「さかな」と読んでよいだろう。国立国語研究所がまとめた『日本言語地図』によれば，全国的には，「さかな」を魚類の総称とする人が，数のうえでは圧倒的に多いとのことである。